# How can I get lastRowId correctly with FMDB?

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

How can I get lastRowId with FMDB?
Method [db lastRowId] always returns 0 for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found, that lastRowId can be retrieved while connection is opened

```
[_database open];
[_database executeUpdate:<some query>];

int64_t lastInsertRowId = [_database lastInsertRowId];
[_database close];

return lastInsertRowId;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSInteger) executeGetLastInsertID:(NSString*)sql
{
    __block NSInteger lastID = -1;

    [self.dbQueue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) {

        if([db executeUpdate:sql]) {
            lastID = (NSInteger)[db lastInsertRowId];
        }

   }];

    return lastID;
}
```